# The requested URL was not found

Tags: php, url, apache

I have Apache/2.4.48 on Windows + PHP version 8.0.8.
When I write [www.sitename.com](http://www.sitename.com) everything is OK - the website is online, but when I clicked on the same link in Facebook, the address become:
[www.sitename.com/?fbclid=IwAR1Os9R3NI3fl2ssnajHMBB2Vmo](http://www.sitename.com/?fbclid=IwAR1Os9R3NI3fl2ssnajHMBB2Vmo)
and the result is "The requested URL was not found".
My default page is index.php and it doesn't need a parameters.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you take that URL and add index.php before the question mark does it then work as intended?